# XNA sound pan depend on X coord

Tags: xna

I need play a sound panning depend on X coord of explosion.

```
Vector2 PositionOfExplosion = ExplosionCoord;
myScreenWidth = 480; //Windows phone
float SoundPan = ??? //Mus be something like MathHelper.Clamp(???, -1, 1);
_explosion1.Play(myVolumen, myPitch, SoundPan); // Pan from -1.0 left to 1.0 right. 0 is center
```

Resuming,

If explosion is in

```
  X=0 Pan= -1 
  ...
  X=120 Pan= -0.5 
  ...
  X=240 Pan= 0 
  ...
  x=360 Pan = 0.5
  ...
  x=480 Pan= 1
```

Sorry my english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pan = (PositionOfExplosion.X - 240.0f) / 240.0f`

You can then clamp to `-1..1`.

Comment: Nice man, easy!... My brain after 12 hours programming don't work very well. Thanks